# Getting a different output in javascript for a proxy website

Tags: javascript, html, output

Here is my code it is in javascript lang:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#countryz').bind('change', function() {
    var trycountry = $('#countryz').val();

    if (trycountry == "ftl" || trycountry == "mesh1" || trycountry == "mesh2" || trycountry == "courir" ||
      trycountry == "nikena" || trycountry == "nikena" || trycountry == "nikeas") {

      if (trycountry == "us" || trycountry == "mx" || trycountry == "cu" || trycountry == "pr" ||
        trycountry == "gt" || trycountry == "ni" || trycountry == "nikena") {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#hst').bind('change', function() {
            var iptype = $('#hst').val();
            if (iptype == "dns") {
              var setcountry = "";
              $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                  var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                  if (httptype == "http|https") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  }
                }).trigger('change');
              });
            } else if (iptype == "iphst") {
              var setcountry = "";
              $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                  var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                  if (httptype == "http|https") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  }
                }).trigger('change');
              });
            }
          }).trigger('change');
        });
      } else if (trycountry == "sg" || trycountry == "id" || trycountry == "my" || trycountry == "ph" ||
        trycountry == "vn" || trycountry == "th" || trycountry == "nikeas") {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#hst').bind('change', function() {
            var iptype = $('#hst').val();
            if (iptype == "dns") {
              var setcountry = "";
              $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                  var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                  if (httptype == "http|https") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  }
                }).trigger('change');
              });
            } else if (iptype == "iphst") {
              var setcountry = "";
              $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                  var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                  if (httptype == "http|https") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  }
                }).trigger('change');
              });
            }
          }).trigger('change');
        });
      } else if (trycountry == "au" || trycountry == "nz" || trycountry == "pg") {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#hst').bind('change', function() {
            var iptype = $('#hst').val();
            if (iptype == "dns") {
              var setcountry = "";
              $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                  var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                  if (httptype == "http|https") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  }
                }).trigger('change');
              });
            } else if (iptype == "iphst") {
              var setcountry = "";
              $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                  var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                  if (httptype == "http|https") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  }
                }).trigger('change');
              });
            }
          }).trigger('change');
        });
      } else {
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#hst').bind('change', function() {
            var iptype = $('#hst').val();
            if (iptype == "dns") {
              var setcountry = "";
              $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                  var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                  if (httptype == "http|https") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  }
                }).trigger('change');
              });
            } else if (iptype == "iphst") {
              var setcountry = "";
              $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                  var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                  if (httptype == "http|https") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                    var texts = "";
                    $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                  }
                }).trigger('change');
              });
            }
          }).trigger('change');
        });
      }
    } else {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#citied').bind('change', function() {
          var elements = $('div.citycont');
          var trycity = $(this).val();

          if (trycountry == "us" || trycountry == "mx" || trycountry == "cu" || trycountry == "pr" ||
            trycountry == "gt" || trycountry == "ni" || trycountry == "nikena") {
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#hst').bind('change', function() {
                var iptype = $('#hst').val();
                if (iptype == "dns") {
                  var setcountry = "";
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                      var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                      if (httptype == "http|https") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      }
                    }).trigger('change');
                  });
                } else if (iptype == "iphst") {
                  var setcountry = "";
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                      var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                      if (httptype == "http|https") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      }
                    }).trigger('change');
                  });
                }
              }).trigger('change');
            });
          } else if (trycountry == "sg" || trycountry == "id" || trycountry == "my" || trycountry == "ph" ||
            trycountry == "vn" || trycountry == "th" || trycountry == "nikeas") {
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#hst').bind('change', function() {
                var iptype = $('#hst').val();
                if (iptype == "dns") {
                  var setcountry = "";
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                      var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                      if (httptype == "http|https") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      }
                    }).trigger('change');
                  });
                } else if (iptype == "iphst") {
                  var setcountry = "";
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                      var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                      if (httptype == "http|https") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      }
                    }).trigger('change');
                  });
                }
              }).trigger('change');
            });
          } else if (trycountry == "au" || trycountry == "nz" || trycountry == "pg") {
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#hst').bind('change', function() {
                var iptype = $('#hst').val();
                if (iptype == "dns") {
                  var setcountry = "";
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                      var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                      if (httptype == "http|https") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      }
                    }).trigger('change');
                  });
                } else if (iptype == "iphst") {
                  var setcountry = "";
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                      var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                      if (httptype == "http|https") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      }
                    }).trigger('change');
                  });
                }
              }).trigger('change');
            });
          } else {
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('#hst').bind('change', function() {
                var iptype = $('#hst').val();
                if (iptype == "dns") {
                  var setcountry = "";
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                      var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                      if (httptype == "http|https") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      }
                    }).trigger('change');
                  });
                } else if (iptype == "iphst") {
                  var setcountry = "";
                  $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#tpz').bind('change', function() {
                      var httptype = $('#tpz').val();
                      if (httptype == "http|https") {
                        var texts = "";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      } else if (httptype == "socks5") {
                        var texts = "12325";
                        $('#foruse').val(trycity);
                      }
                    }).trigger('change');
                  });
                }
              }).trigger('change');
            });
          }
        }).trigger('change');
      });
    }

  }).trigger('change');
});
</script>
```

Above is my code, what's weird is I am getting a diff output, I should be getting constantine but durres is coming out:

Am I missing anything? I'm really having some difficulties finishing this proxy reseller website.

[image: Different output]

Comment: Some of the countries in your second `if` aren't in the first `if`, so they can never be matched. Why do you include them?

Comment: There's no need to have `$(document).ready()` inside another `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()`.

Comment: I don't see `constantine` or `durres` anywhere in the code. Where do they come from, and why should you get one instead of the other?

Comment: Can you add the HTML to make this a [mre]?

Comment: Posted my html code below pls check